# Python decode french char in html email attachment

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-email

I'm trying to decode an html attachment file of an email that I take on an IMAP Server.
If the html file contain normal character it's working without problem, but when you have some french `é` character I have this: `"vous a \xc3\xa9t\xc3\xa9 envoy\xc3\xa9e par"`
I also have all `\n` `\r` that appear.

I use beautifulsoup to make some search on the html code. I also use a loop to check all the mail(Not present in this code)

```
imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("server",993)
imap_server.login(username, password)
imap_server.select("test")
result, data = imap_server.uid('search', None, "UnSeen")
latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[-1]
result, data = imap_server.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
raw_email = data[0][1]
raw_email=str(raw_email, 'UTF8')
msg = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
```

I walk in the mail, if I find some html I decode it from base64 and send to beautifulsoup.
After that I print it with utf-8 conversion. If I replace encode.('utf-8') by latin-1 I have also special char.

```
if msg.is_multipart(): 
    for part in msg.walk():
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
            attachment= (part.get_payload(decode=1))
            soup=BeautifulSoup(attachment)
            print (soup.prettify().encode('utf-8'))
        else:
            print ("No HTML")
```

I tried to encode,decode in a lot a charset without having something nice.
I have also tried with `base64.b64decode(text).decode('utf-16')` but still have the same `\xc3\xa9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see the special characters *because* you are encoding to UTF-8 or Latin-1:

```
>>> print('\xe9')
é
>>> print('\xe9'.encode('utf8'))
b'\xc3\xa9'
>>> print('\xe9'.encode('latin1'))
b'\xe9'
>>> print('Hello world!\n'.encode('utf8'))
b'Hello world!\n'
```

When printing a bytes literal, Python shows the `repr()` representation of the value, which replaces any byte that does *not* represent a printable ASCII codepoint with the `\x..` escape sequence; some are replaced with the shorter two-character escapes, such as `\r` and `\n`. This makes the representation both re-usable as a Python bytes literal and more easily logged to files and terminals not set up for international character sets.

`print()` handles encoding for you. Just print the `.prettify()` output *directly*.

If printing Unicode to your terminal or console does not work, and instead raises a `UnicodeDecodeError`, your terminal or console is not configured to handle Unicode text properly. Consult the [PrintFail Python Wiki page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails) to troubleshoot.

Comment: If I don't encode to utf8, print doesn't work. With your example I have this: >>> print('\xe9')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @user2397639: Then your terminal is not configured properly. See http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails